# Producing a PDF from a single R function

Tags: r, r-markdown, roxygen2

Imagine, you define an R function to share with a pal, only a single function. In case of, you decide later to include this function in a package, you document it using Roxygen comments and tags (e. g. `#' @name my_function`). Is it possible to produce a PDF from this single R file? If yes, how?

Comment: Do you mean just export the text of the function? Or the whole file from the package source?

Comment: I mean only the documentation for the function, independent if the script defining the function is in a package or in a project folder.

Comment: If you type the function name with no `()` you'll get the code for it in the console (e.g. `read.csv` instead of `read.csv()`).  You can use `capture.output()` to direct this to a variable and then export that to pdf however you need to.  This doesn't work for primitives etc but should work for simple user defined functions.

Comment: Since it's a source file with inline roxygen comments, I'm assuming at some point you've roxygenized the package (or source file) into a file ending in `.Rd` (in the `./man/` directory of a package). You can then run (in a shell, not in R) `R CMD Rd2pdf *.Rd` to create a pdf with the applicable `.Rd` files. This requires having at least a modicum of TeXlive installed/available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** We will use the file lc.R as an example which we first download from github.  First use kitten to create the boilerplate for a package.  Copy lc.R to it.  Then run document from devtools to roxygenize it and finally use Rd2pdf to create the pdf, lc.pdf .

```
library(devtools)
library(pkgKitten)
library(roxygen2)

# set up lc in lc.R to use as a test example
u <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mailund/lc/master/R/lc.R"
download.file(u, "./lc.R")

# create package containing lc.R - ignore any NAMESPACE warnings
kitten("lc")
file.copy("lc.R", "./lc/R")

# roxygenize it generating an Rd file
document("lc")
file.copy("lc/man/lc.Rd", ".")

# convert Rd file to pdf
R <- file.path(R.home("bin"), "R")
cmd <- paste(R, "CMD Rd2pdf lc.Rd")
system(cmd, wait = FALSE)
```

**2)** There used to be a package on CRAN named [document](https://cran.r-project.org/package=document) (or see [gitlab](https://%20https://gitlab.com/fvafrCU/document)) which does the same thing in one step but it was removed last year. Note that the document package depends on the [fritools](https://cran.r-project.org/package=fritools) (or see [gitlab](https://%20https://gitlab.com/fvafrcu/fritools)) package which was also removed.  The source of both are archived on CRAN and on gitlab and it may be possible to build them yourself. (Update June 14, 2023: The document and fritools packages are back on CRAN.)

```
library(document)
setwd("...dir containing lc.R ...")
if (!dir.exists("doc")) dir.create("doc")
document("lc.R", "doc", check = FALSE)
```

**3)** This approach does not create a PDF but it does allow one to view formatted help for a script converting it from the roxygen2 markup to HTML showing it in the browser.  Note that the box package should not be attached, i.e. do not use a `library(box)` statement.  Assume that lc.R is in the current directory -- see the download.file statement in (1) above. The code below may generate warnings or errors but it still works to bring up the help for the lc function in lc.R showing it in the default browser.

```
box::use(./lc)
box::help(lc$lc)
```

Comment: Wow! I tried it and made it work. Nevertheless I had to modify the command line before the last to `cmd <- "R CMD Rd2pdf lc.Rd"`, because I work in Ubuntu. I guess, this may also work in Windows, provided that "bin/R.exe" is in the PATH variable.

Comment: I'm thinking, this can be packed in a function and the intermediate package folder can be created in `tempdir()`...

Comment: This does not depend on the PATH variable.  It works in Windows because R.exe is always at the location shown.  On other platforms you may be able to replace R.home("bin/R.exe") with just R if R is on the PATH or replace it with the entire path to R if not.

Comment: My point was, with "path to R.exe" in the variable PATH, you may be able to call R from your "terminal/command prompt" (e.g. R CMD ..). In Linux you don't have *.exe file for R.

Comment: `file.path(R.home("bin"), "R")` works on my Windows system and I believe it works  on all platforms to find the R executable.  Please let me know if that works on your platform.